# How to continuously subtract the left of two moving divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to subtract the `left` value of two moving divs i am able to continuously calculate their `left` using `setInterval` but when i try to subtract their values it shows the error `NaN`

http://jsfiddle.net/mmtdv9ew/2/

HTML

```
<p id="z"></p><p id="x"></p><p id="y"></p>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

CSS

```
#a{
-webkit-animation:mv 10s infinite;
left:250px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:green;
position:absolute;
}

#b{
position:absolute;
-webkit-animation:mvs 10s infinite;
z-index:10;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mv{
0%{left:100px;}
50%{left:500px;}
100%{left:250px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mvs{
0%{left:0;}
50%{left:600px;}
100%{left:0px;}
}
```

JQuery

```
setInterval(function(){
var x=$('#a').css('left');
var y=$('#b').css('left');
$('#z').text(x);
 $('#y').text(y);
});
setInterval(function(){
var a=parseInt($('#z').text() , 10);
var b=parseInt($('#x').text() , 10);
var c= a - b ;
$('#x').text(c);
});
```

Comment: You could have found this by yourself by logging the value of your variables :)

Comment: @sodawillow i had tried with `parseInt` but missed the integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo : replace x with y in `var b=parseInt($('#x').text() , 10);`

See updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mmtdv9ew/3/

Reading again, and because your code is overcomplicated, I may have missed the precise **logic** error

Simplified code (wrapped in a function executed after page elements are loaded):

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        var x = parseInt($('#a').css('left'), 10);
        var y = parseInt($('#b').css('left'), 10);
        var c = x - y ;
        $('#x').text(c);
    });
});
```

Comment: I could swear that i tried this but a bit different